# is there a way to withdraw from killed contract?

Tags: solidity

I put a contract into "self destruct" and some erc20 tokens are stuck in that contract address. Is there any way I could retrieve that back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract address private key is unknown (was never generated during the deployment), so you cannot sign a transaction from its address.

If you deployed the contract using the [CREATE2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) opcode and it already contained a function to withdraw tokens, you can redeploy the contract using the same bytecode, the same `salt` value and from the same deployer address.

Otherwise, there's no way to retrieve the tokens. All other methods of trying to redeploy the contract (e.g. if you previously deployed it with the regular `CREATE` opcode) would result in a different contract address.